# lua atempt to index ? a nil ? - computercraft

Tags: lua, computercraft

I'm playing project ozone 2 and I have a pain with automating the reactor but this is the only bit I cant solve can anyone tell me why this part is having an error when the rest aren't
problem its at the bottom of the list

```
term.setCursorPos(11, 11):
print("word")
```

and all of them

```
term.setCursorPos(11, 2);
print("Max RF:")
term.setCursorPos(11, 3);
print("Max Thru:")

 term.setCursorPos(11, 5);
 print("Cur In:")
 term.setCursorPos(11, 6);
 print("Cur Out:")
 term.setCursorPos(11, 7);
 print("Cur Bal:")

term.setCursorPos(11, 9);
print("Stored:")
term.setCursorPos(11, 10);
print("Filled:")
term.setCursorPos(11, 11):
print("word")
```

and the hole code if you need to look at it
sorry for the mess im new to all this

https://pastebin.com/JuX5RaAh

Comment: The two lines in the first block are not valid Lua code.

Comment: then how do the rest of them work? plese explane im not that good with code

Comment: You have a colon (":") at the end of the first line of code and that shouldn't be there.

Comment: You see how all the other `term.setCursorPos()` lines end with `;`?

Comment: oh i seee thank you i didnt notice that the font coputer craft uses made that difucult to notus

Comment: Note that Lua does not require you to end the lines with `;` but if you do that, you should do it on every line and not alternate between "using it" and "not using it"

Answer (score 4):

Changing the `:` at the end of that line to a `;` like the others should fix the problem.